# What is a Cardinal Animal?

Tags: pattern, word-property, animals

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If the name of an animal conforms to a special rule, I call it a Cardinal Animal™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Cardinal Animal™ | Not Cardinal Animal™ |
| --- | --- |
| EAGLE | GOOSE |
| GIRAFFE | CARIBOU |
| MONITOR LIZARD | GENTOO PENGUIN |
| FALCON | TURKEY |
| DUCK | COOT |
| HEDGEHOG | PLATYPUS |
| CAT | DOG |

CSV Version:

```
Cardinal Animal™,Not Cardinal Animal™
EAGLE,GOOSE
GIRAFFE,CARIBOU
MONITOR LIZARD,GENTOO PENGUIN
FALCON,TURKEY
DUCK,COOT
HEDGEHOG,PLATYPUS
CAT,DOG
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Cardinal Animal™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Cardinal Animals™, many more exist.

Hint:

> The pairing across each row tells you something about one half of the pattern

Answer (score 26, accepted):

An animal is a Cardinal Animal™ if

> The first letter of its name, converted to a number via A1Z26, is the length of its name.

They are called Cardinal because

> Their first (cardinal, maybe?) letter can be treated as a cardinal number for the length of its name.

Comment: So a cardinal, oddly, is *not* a Cardinal Animal!

Comment: The name may also refer to the idea of cardinality in mathematics, which is the number of elements in a set.

Comment: But a Cat is. :p

Comment: The name 'Cardinal Animal' was intended to be a play on words, an attempt to distract with no actual tie to animals and the actual pattern, and also a minor hint at the solution -- which of course you guys found in a matter of hours. Since this is my first ever attempt at writing one of these, feedback and thoughts on how to improve are much welcomed.